# Is aviation software translated into the users' native language desirable over English?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, commercial-operations, software

I want to build some software containing information about aircraft, like a logbook. Nothing related with avionics.

I know that default language in the aviation industry is English, but in the case of online software, could professionals be interested in using an online logbook or MRO software showing in another language besides English?

Comment: A native language version is very helpful for training. If people are confronted with new concepts AND new vocabulary to convey those concepts, their learning load is doubled. A native version of educational software would reduce the load and help the trainee to progress. The benefit of a native version for experienced pilots would be small, however.

Answer (score 2):

English is the native language of aviation... 
I myself always get mightily annoyed at poorly translated software, which is 90% of all software provided in multiple languages. IF you provide multiple languages, allow the user to switch between them AND get professional translators to do the work.

Would it sell? Probably, if it's good enough. But I don't see the language options as being a major selling point. Certainly not so big that having them will make a large number of potential customers choose it over another product that has more options elsewhere but lacks language selection.
In some places maybe, where English is less than common and not generally used by ATC.
Whether that's where your intended market is I don't know.